# Online Course to become Salesforce Developer

Tags: trailhead, learning

I am a full stack developer with 6 year of experience in technologies like JavaScript css HTML Linux c# mysql, I wanted to know what will be the best online course for getting started with development in salesforce, like apex programming, visual force etc..
Any particular course on Udemy ?

Comment: [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) would be my first stop.

Comment: As @TSmith said, Trailhead is a great resource. I'd also look at the specific certification you're looking to take and refer to the [Certification Journey EBook](https://www.salesforce.com/form/services-training/certification-journey-ebook.jsp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Trailheads!

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/

It holds all the information you need regarding development for Salesforce including Apex, Lightning and how to build apps for the platform, its also completely free and fun to do